# How to update service proxy aspnet boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I just downloaded the latest version 3.7 of AspNetBoilerplate with Angular 5 and I was trying to use my new service that I created.  It was not showing up in the service proxy.   How do I update the auto generated code from swagger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the angular\nswag> folder.  There is a refresh.bat file in there.  Execute that file while the project is running in VS 2017 and swagger is showing.  It will then update you services so you can call them in your code.

Comment: Running refresh.bat from the command prompt will give you response also.

Answer (score 5):

**Step1: Open PowerShell**

**Step2: Go to directory where is your project located and locate** `\angualar\nswag`
which should lool like :  `PS C:\Users\myname\myangularporject\angular\nswag>`
(Check by typing ls or dir and you should see two files named `refresh.bat` and `service.config.nswag`)

**Step3:** Type `.\refresh.bat`

You are  done !

Remember you only need this task if you add new service in your server but you do not neeed to use when modified existing service. Check it out [here](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/latest/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular).

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same thing using "Node.js Command Prompt" like in the Power Shell.

**Step 1 :** Go to the project location, using "cd" command

```
    Eg :-  C:\Users\Name\MyAngularPorject\angular> cd nswag
```

**Step 2 :** Run below command

```
    Eg :- C:\Users\Name\MyAngularPorject\angular\nswag> start refresh.bat
```

Finish.. Simple..